# Displaying the parent term first in Views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have managed to create to organize my content using the Taxonomy module, it is 2 levels deep.

```
Level 1 
    > Level 1-a 
        > Level 1-a-i
    > Level 1-b 
        > Level 1-b-ii
Level 2 
    > Level 2-a 
        > Level 2-a-i
Level 3 
    > Level 3-a 
        > Level 3-a-i
```

I display this using the Views module.
But the problem I am facing is that the view displays all terms,

```
Level 1
Level 1-a
Level 1-a-i
Level 1-b
Level 1-b-ii
```

What I am trying to achieve on this view is something like this

```
Level 1
Level 2
Level 3
```

And then when the user clicks a level it will display child, until they reach the deepest level of the taxonomy

```
Level 1-a
Level 1-b
```

and then for example selecting **Level 1-a**

```
Level 1-a-i
Level 1-a-ii
Level 1-a-iii
```

Comment: What if you grouped the terms based on the Parent term?

Comment: @KyleTaylored : Where will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The [Views Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) module might be what you're after.